# Canon EOS 700D - Locked in Q mode

Tags: camera-settings, canon-700d

I have a Canon EOS 700D that seems to be stuck in Q mode.

None of the buttons work, the touch screen doesn't let you press anything.

Depending on how lucky you are there are times when the camera acts normally. But the second you turn it off and back on it reverts to this locked mode.

If you have any suggestions of possible fixes that would be fantastic.

The camera currently has a Canon 24-105mm Image stabilizer lens on it as well.

See attached image for the "Q" mode I'm referring to.
[image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you mean by locked and what it is you can't to do but can't do because the camera is locked?
Also, I see that you are i manual mode, indicated by the "M" in the top left corner. Is this intended? In manual mode you have to dial in all the settings manually. Is this the reason you feal the camera is locked? If you switch the top dial to e.g. A or P mode, is the camera still locked?

Comment: Could be a stuck "Q" button?

Answer (score 1):

Just saw this question. It’s new to me

This answer is a DSLR in general not for the 700D check this site out

https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/2750759

Press the info button and it should get you out of the stuck q button/display mode